# jQuery animate not firing callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects, jquery-easing

I have the following jQuery animate function:

```
$myDiv.animate({ "left": "0%" }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutExpo' }, 
    function () {
        alert('hi');
    }
);
```

The animation itself works. `$myDiv` slides with the `easeInOutExpo` effect, as desired. However, the callback function is never fired. To test it, I changed the callback to just `alert("hi");`, as you can see above. Still doesn't work.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you've set `$myDiv` to equal `$("#myDiv")`, it should be the latter.

Comment: @AstroCB Yeah, $myDiv is equal to that.  It's dynamic and changes which is why it's a variable.  It is properly set and the animation does work.  Just not the complete function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Qk4n/)

```
  $("#myDiv").animate({ "left": "0%" }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutExpo' , 
    complete:function () {
        alert('hi');
    }
   }
);
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks @Dola  Know why that's the case (why you had to specify complete:)?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Nullqwerty Well, You can always refer to the jQuery documentation for usage examples. You can check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I had been.  But didn't understand about mixing formats as @AstroCB described below.  Now I do.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things that need fixing here:

1. Make sure you've included jQuery UI in your code, because [`easeInOutExpo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) is not part of the standard jQuery library.
2. Your syntax is wrong: you're mixing up the two different options for the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

It's either

```
$(element).animate(properties [,duration] [,easing] [,complete]);
```

or

```
$(element).animate(properties, options)
```

where `options` is an object formatted like this:

```
{
  duration: number,
  easing: string,
  complete: function,
}
```

You've gone with the second option, so you need to format it properly to use the `complete` attribute of the `options` object for your function:

```
$myDiv.animate({
    "left": "0%",
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
    complete: function () {
        alert('hi');
    },
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Z944R/2/)

Alternatively, you could use the first format option:

```
$("#myDiv").animate({
    "left": "0%",
}, 1000, "easeInOutExpo", function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Z944R/)

Comment: Thanks @AstroCB  I'm new to JQuery and just learning about the formatting that you described.  Thanks for the tips.  I do have the easing library in there (like I was saying, that part of it worked fine).  But the format piece of it is why the callback function wasn't working as Dola pointed out above.  Thanks again.  Your explanation helped me greatly understand.  Didn't realize there were issues of mixing formats.  Now I do.  Thanks

Comment: @Nullqwerty No problem; I'm glad I could help. I'd recommend taking a look through the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com), as it does a great job of laying out the varying syntax and requirements of each piece of the library.

Answer (score 0):

> One way is use of **JQuery Promise**

```
$myDiv.animate({ "left": "0%" }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutExpo' }).promise().done(function(){

     alert('hi done');

});
```